# CGAL sqrt function does not return argument type

Tags: cgal

I want to use the CGAL::sqrt function to compute the length of a vector. Here is my code:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::FT NT;
typedef K::Point_2 Point;
typedef K::Vector_2 Vector;

// pt1, pt2 are of type Point
Vector v1(pt1, pt2);
NT norm1 = CGAL::sqrt<NT>(v1 * v1);
```

However, the above code throws me an error during compilation:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'CGAL::Null_functor::result_type' to 'CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Epeck represents numbers as rationals, so you cannot compute a sqrt there. You can use a different kernel (Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel_with_sqrt for instance), or compute an approximate_sqrt.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Got it. Thank you.